# Can I reuse my concrete shower pan?

Tags: bathroom, shower, tile

House was built in 2004. I'm remodeling a small bathroom with a shower in it. The shower did not leak, it was just dated.

I removed all the original cement board and tile. The shower pan is concrete and I was able to scrape away all the tile. It has some high/low spots because I chiseled too deep in some spots but I figured I can fill in those spots with thinset.

I did cut into the membrane around the curb, I didn't think it was important considering I planned on covering the curb with thinset, then cement board, and waterproofing it

Can I just use this shower pan? To me it seems fine, but would like more opinions.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You're adding a second layer of waterproofing? Does that create a mold concern? (I'm not a shower expert.)

Comment: @isherwood looks like most of the original waterproofing has been removed, so a new layer seems appropriate.